# Set backgroundImage in HTML with URL pulled from JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

```js
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1PzTMW6xH5cjLgvLn_LOq25XEbmrCw2MP9C9vvt4rhoM/1/public/full?alt=json')
ourRequest.onload = function() {
var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
var TEXT = ourData.feed.entry[2].gs$cell.inputValue;
var IMG = ourData.feed.entry[3].gs$cell.inputValue;


console.log(TEXT);
console.log(IMG);

document.getElementById('testoutput').innerHTML = TEXT;
document.getElementById('backgroundIMG').style.backgroundImage = "url('IMG')";


};
ourRequest.send();
```

```css
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */
        }

div {
text-align: left;
min-height: 100%;
font-family: motiva-sans, sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
font-size: 15vw;
padding: 15px;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/vbl6jef.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Sheets - Werkend</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="backgroundIMG"><div>
  <div id="testoutput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm working on a HTML document that gets its styling from Google Sheets JSON data. So far it works for setting properties such as backgroundColor.

Right now i'm trying to set the backgroundImage and have set a variable that contains the url: 
`document.getElementById('backgroundIMG').style.backgroundImage = "url('IMG')";`

When I console.log the variable it returns the url just fine. When I place the URL directly into the code above, it works. When I put the variable in the code (like shown above) it won't load the URL.

My limited knowledge stops me from searching the right terms on what is going on here. I have tried reading up on variables but no succes yet.

Can anyone point me in the right direction by either telling me what to read up on or by offering a sollution based on my code below?

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: Thanks again, clicked the checkmark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not using the IMG variable, just IMG as a string, so try:

```
document.getElementById('backgroundIMG').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + IMG + ")";
```

Adding a variable to a string:

"Traditional" ways (plus sign is expands a string):

```
let s = "number: " + num;

let s = 'number: ' + num;
```

ES6 template literals:

```
let s = `number: ${num}`
```

Get more information on these links:

[JS Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings)

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thanks a lot Tamas! Could you tell me what I would have to read up on for this and similar issues? Would really help me the next time if I understood why I needed the +'s.

Comment: You can use single or double quotation marks to define a string, and to use a variable inside a string you have to "quit" from the string, and add the variable to it, that's why the `+` needed.